# How to refresh a react component that doesn't rely on state

Tags: reactjs, select, components, state, refresh

I have a react modal component that is a collection of selects.
Although it informs state when the fields are updated it does not rely on the state to render. However, there is a refresh button which is designed to reset the selects and reset the state back to default value.
Is there a proper way in this situation to refresh the component given that it only relies on that state to show the default values once the refresh button is pressed?

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far. SO is not the place to get other people to write your code for you. Your best bet is to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

> Generally there is no concept of full page refresh in SPA.

If you want to reset, you can use one of the approaches i.e., having a `key` on select or the modal itself and when the button is clicked just change the key which would create select or the modal again from scratch which would set the default value ....

[Resetting using keys in React - Docs reference](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-2-resetting-state-with-a-key)